# Angular UI Bootstrap Modal Dialog Close Event

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

How do I detect when an [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) modal dialog is closed?

I need to know when the dialog closes so I can broadcast a `loginCancelled` event using the [angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) library to prevent my Angular UI from hanging, especially after closing the modal via clicking on the backdrop.

Comment: Can you explain why the promise isn't sufficient for this? That's exactly what it's intended for :)

Comment: If you're discarding the most obvious and correct way of solving the problem than at least try and provide some explanation behind your decision.

Comment: @Stewie very well. I shall look into using the promise. Redacted part in question about not using the promise.

Answer (score 16):

This works for clicking on the backdrop and pressing the esc key if you are opting in on that.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/app/yourtemplate.html',
    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
    windowClass: 'modal',
    keyboard: true,
    resolve: {
        yourResulst: function () {
            return 'foo';
        }
    }
});

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, yourResulst) {

    var constructor = function () {
       // init stuff
    }

    constructor();

    $modalInstance.result.then(function () {
        // not called... at least for me
    }, function () {
        // hit's here... clean up or do whatever
    });

    // VVVV other $scope functions and so on...

};
```

**UPDATE**: alternative approach

I have no idea why this way is not documented at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ... but I find it much better. You can now use that page's controller or use a specific controller with the controller as syntax. You could even utilize ng-include for the content of the modal, if you want separation on html. The following works with no JS needed in the controller to setup/configure the modal, as long as you have bootstrap/bootstrapUI included in your project/site

```
<div class="row">

    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Open Example Modal</button>

</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal Example</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding-bottom:0px;">

                <h3>model markup goes here</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: // not called... at least for me. This section of your code will be called after successfully submitting from the modal. Its basically $modalInstance.result.then(success, error/cancel)

Comment: @wakurth Acutally it's not documented because it's not a part of bootstrap-ui itself, you're just using the original data-attribute-styled bootstrap modal interface.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: in the `$modalInstance.result.then`, can you get access to the parent container element that called the modal ? I'm asking this because I'm struggling with this issue right now.

Comment: Hi wakurth, can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583136/bootstrap-modal-popup-open-and-close-using-angularjs-not-working

Answer (score 13):

I finished with the following code:

```
$modal.open(modalOptions).result.finally(function(){
  console.log('modal has closed');
});
```

This way you can avoid the method then()

Comment: It's still a promise. Can't see any advantages over typical way.

Comment: This works best for me! I have a common modal service wired up, and it makes a lot of sense to clean up with the `result` promise. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rafael Motta, can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583136/bootstrap-modal-popup-open-and-close-using-angularjs-not-working

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({...});
        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
            //something to do on close
        });
```

Comment: `finally` would be better than `then` to catch them clicking off of the modal as well.