# How to capture the pressing of the ESC key to close a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angular-ui

I have a bootstrap modal that I'm using to change sizes of thumbnails. I have a save and cancel button on the bootstrap modal. If I hit the cancel button I have the thumbnails returning to the previous size. I would like the same behavior by hitting ESC or clicking outside the modal. However, I have been unable to capture these events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bootstrap 3 you can use

```
$('#my-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  window.alert('event fired!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jorge, I totally believe this will work. However, I am unable to create a div class=modal in order to assign the modal id.  The "appears" but it's hidden it seems.  As soon as I remove the class=modal and just leave the individual modal-header, modal-body, modal-footer.. The modal actually displays.  But I need the top div of the modal class to assign the id to use the hidden.bs.modal.

Comment: How do you create the modal in the first place. Refer to documentation: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals ) the data-target="myModal" is your modal id

Comment: So my problem with that is, I don't have a button on that page that's launching the modal for me to use the data-target.  I'm launching the modal from an "Icon" that is placed on an element directive. So the modal is being launched from a different location. I'm using angular

`{Icon: "resources/icons/music236", Caption: "Preferences", Separate: true, OnClick: $scope.openPreferences}`

Comment: `$scope.openPreferences = function () {
                        $modal.open({
                            animation: false,
                            templateUrl: 'pages/preferences.html',
                            controller: 'userpreferencesController',
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            keyboard: 'false'
                        }).result;
                    }`

Comment: then I hope this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825880/angular-ui-bootstrap-modal-dialog-close-event

Comment: Thanks, that definitely catches the escape and clicking of the backdrop... Now I just need to figure out how to execute the code in my controller based on that action.  I'm sure it has something to do with promises and defers which are very complicated :(

Comment: Thanks @Jorge... Finally figured this monster out with your help. FYI
`.result.finally(function ()
  {angular.element("#userPreferenceModal").scope().resetPreferences();
 });`

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 5, the syntax is

```
const modalElem = document.getElementById('modaldlg');
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalElem);

modalElem.addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', (event) => {
    window.alert('event fired!');
});
```