# ionicModal vs angular ui modal event for closing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a modal that I show.. takes up part of the screen, and can be closed by clicking outside of the modals `div` tag.

```
$scope.showMyModal = function() {
    $scope.modified = false;
    $scope.modal.show();
    var m = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-backdrop hide")[0];
    if(m != undefined){
      m.parentNode.removeChild(m);
    }
    $scope.myDataLoad();
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
};
```

I thought I could listen for the `modal.closing` event, in the case where the user edited something and we want to prompt them to save.. but this event is not firing.  Do I have the wrong event?

I cannot wrap it in the promise style found here:

[Angular UI Bootstrap Modal Dialog Close Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825880/angular-ui-bootstrap-modal-dialog-close-event)

because by that time it's too late to prompt for "Do you want to save, Yes/Cancel"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct event is `modal.hidden`, as stated [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/). Inside your modal controller, you should have code like this:

```
$scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
  // Execute action
});
```

Comment: edited my question to reflect the proper code.. I am using `modal.closing`

right now my code is on the controller the modal is shown in.. is there another controller or a default controller?

Comment: added the entire function call that shows the modal

Comment: Are you using Angular UI modals? What is `$scope.modal` initialized to?

Comment: When you ask about what it's initialized to, are you meaning what controller is it instantiated on?  There's a controller on the page where the modal can be opened.   I believe that controller is the same one for the modal

Comment: Is it an Angular UI modal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96601/discussion-between-erik-and-jfischer00).